# JavaFX overlapping flags

Tags: javafx

In javaFX, how can I overlap multiple flags in the same row. I would also like the flags to be at the bottom of the scene with the top, center, left and right parts completely empty.

the flags should overlap sort of like this:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020215/images/masking/compop01.png

notice this is a picture of 2 flags overlapping..
I don't even know where to begin with this.

Comment: You should inline the image, because it might become unavailable when the question is archived on here.

Answer (score 0):

You create a [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html), but [ImageViews](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) on it and position them using [setLayoutX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX-double-) (and Y). The stacking is according to the order you put the images on the pane. Alternatively you can use [toFront](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toFront--) and [toBack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toBack--) to set the z-order.